# a bushy -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

From the song "[I Am Australian](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/seekers/iamaustralian.html)" by the Australian pop group *The Seekers*.

> I'm a daughter of a digger
>   Who sought the mother lode
>   The girl became a woman
>   On the long and dusty road
>   I'm a child of the depression
>   I saw the good times come
>   I'm **a bushy**, I'm a battler
>   I am Australian

All the dictionaries I looked in, *bushy* is only listed as an adjective.

Comment: You can find it under **bushie**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not Australian, but if I had to guess, I would say it might be a shortened version of "Australian Bushman," which can refer to anyone who lives in rural Australia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_bush#Australia

I think the idea is that they are describing the identities of various types of people who live in Australia, and singing from a point of view that encompasses all the different identities. This idea is also supported by the next verse:

> We are one
>   But we are many
>   And from all the lands on earth we come
>   We'll share a dream
>   And sing with one voice
>   I am, you are, we are Australian

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when I visited Australia I was exposed to the unique Australian language. "Bushy" is a slang term used for those people who live in "the bush" which is the woodland area of Australia, and different than "the outback."